# VBA to SQL stored procedure parameter formatting issue

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Can anyone one help me with this?

I'm trying to use a variable from a stored procedure to filter another stored procedure in an Excel macro but the variable value isn't getting passed to the 2nd stored procedure.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = conn.Execute("[dbo].[ufnSectorLevel] 3 ")
rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF

GetSector = rs.Fields(0).Value

qry = "[dbo].[ufnDemographicAgeSector] '" & GetSector & "'"

Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs1 = conn.Execute(qry)
```

I also tried this but with the same result.

```
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "ufnDemographicAgeSector"

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Sector", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, GetSector)
cmd.Execute
```

The stored procedure works as I want it to if I do this.

```
GetSector = "Acute Corporate"
```

or if I enter the text directly into the parameter like this.

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Sector", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, "Acute Corporate")
```

I've also tried chr(39) around the variable and field value but nothing triggers the filter in stored procedure #2.

Does anyone know of anything else I can try?

Comment: In your first example. did you verify whether GetSector actually has a value?

Comment: @BrianMStafford  Hi, yes, it always has a value, ithe one I gave as an example is the first records in the table I'm looping through.

Comment: I guess you need to verify that the GetSector variable contains what you think it does. Maybe use Debug.Print() to show in the output window. Maybe also Dim GetSector as String may coerce the value from the recordset into a string, if it is some other variant type.

Comment: @DS_London Hi, I've done both of those things. The variable does contain the data. When I debug,printed the only odd thing was the closing quote was placed on the row below.

Comment: Perhaps then your string contains some extra character (eg \n)? Try checking len() and seeing if it is what you think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DS_London I discoved that the length count in the variable was higher, by 2, than the string characters.

I had created the lookup table by copy and pasting into the sequal table from excel so even though it looked fine it must have had addition charaters attached(don't ever do that!)

Thanks to DS and everyone who took a look.